# Is it possible to push an image build with Kaniko to an Oracle container registry?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kaniko, container-registry

My scenario: I have an image of a self-hosted Azure agent deployed on Kubernetes and I will need to build & push a docker image of a microservice using that agent.

For that, I recently began learning about Kaniko and while reading the documentation, I realized there was no support for oracle registry. However, as it is said [here](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko#pushing-to-different-registries), "configuring another credential helper should allow pushing to a different registry", but I have no clue how to do that...

I know there are [other alternatives](https://sprinkle-twinkles.medium.com/alternatives-to-build-an-image-without-using-docker-daemon-using-oci-initiatives-like-buildah-d0f3ae35e414), so before proceeding with Kaniko (which was recommended to me), I would first like to know if it is possible to push an image to the oracle registry

Comment: yes you can push the image to oracle registry.

Comment: Yes I've tried and it works! Thank you :)

Comment: feel free to add your answer and update the status of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible (thanks Harsh Manvar).

After giving the documentation a more throughly read, all I needed to set (that was specific of the Oracle registry) was a kubernetes secret with the valid credentials, formatted as explained [this section](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko/blob/main/docs/tutorial.md#create-a-secret-that-holds-your-authorization-token).

After that it is a matter of following instructions in the kaniko docs.